# nginx rewrite url pattern middle of url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

This nginx rule works great for me for a full specified file path

```
rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php last;
```

When I acces sitemap.xml it works as expected but in the background sitemap.php is requested. So far so goode.

Another problem arised and I need to rewrite the last part of existing urls

`rewrite ^doctor-solution.html/ doctor-answer.html/` permanent;
What I want to achive is when an old url like `https://example.com/case12232-doctor-solution.html/` is accessed it must be redirected to

```
https://example.com/case12232-doctor-answer.html/
```

But My rule doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Can I do something like, this gives me error

```
 rewrite ^/([a-z]+)-doctor-solution.html/$ /{$1}-doctor-answer.html/;
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/([a-z]+)-doctor-solution.html/$ /$1-doctor-answer.html/ permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to include digit in your regex , and made a error to reference a matching pattern , so this is `$1` and not `{$1}` ( see Richard Simith comment )

In you case the solution

```
rewrite ^/([a-z0-9]+)-doctor-solution.html/$ /$1-doctor-answer.html/ redirect;
```

More documentation on 
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: unfortunately I get error 404